# Changing the Location (region) of Logic Apps? Or Function Apps? Of App Service Plans and Storage Accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a Resource group that has multiple Function Apps and Logic Apps from 3 different Locations (regions, for ex: West US, Central US, South Central US, etc.). As a consequence of this, I have 3 App Service plans (one for each location), and 2 different Storage accounts (from two different locations).

I would like all resources in my Resource Group to all be from one location. I heard that having all these locations can be more expensive. There is no special reason they are from different locations.

**Q1**: Is there a way I can change these resources to all one region?

**Q2**: Is there a way I can consolidate / merge the App Service Plans and Storage accounts?

Comment: The cost will be the same, but having resources in multiple regions may affect the performance due latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. The only way to do this is to re-create the resources in a new location. Check out ARM templates for doing so. To export your Function or Logic App settings, go to the Export Template menu item in their Azure Portal management blade.
2. You can use the same App Service Plan when you recreate these resources. Just know that if you stick multiple Functions or Logic Apps on the same App Service Plan, they'll share resources. Make sure you provision accordingly. One Function going nuts can starve the other resources. You can also use the same Storage account, but best practices are to have a separate storage account per Function.